# ICS: any way to restore the "combined view" email notification I had on Gingerbread?

Tags: email, samsung-nexus-s, notifications, 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, stock-email-app

My Nexus S was OTA-upgraded yesterday to Ice Cream Sandwich 4.0.3 from 2.3 (Gingerbread).  I use the stock mail app with two email accounts. On Gingerbread, if I got new emails in both accounts, I would get a single notification that pointed to my "combined inbox".  This was convenient.

On ICS, I get two notifications instead, doubling the time needed to read my new mail because I have to visit each mailbox separately. Annoying!

Yes, I realize that if I only have a few emails I can read them right from the notification bar, but I get 100+ emails per day so I usually get the "bulk" notifications.

Is there a way on the ICS email app to restore the gingerbread behavior to have a single notification pointing to my "combined view" inbox instead of two separate notifications?

Comment: If you get hundreds of emails per day, having to switch from one to the other once does not exactly double the time you need.

Comment: yep, but unfortunately I need to check my mail 10+ times per day, so the cost is not just one switch but it's one switch every time I need to check my mail.

Comment: Or rather if you have 100+ emails per day, you really don't need notification as you'd be constantly checking your email anyway. Use priority inbox and disable the notification for the nonpriority emails, and get into the habit of bulk processing your emails.

Answer (score 3):

I finally gave up on the stock email client for Android 4.0 because of this problem and others. Now I use [Enhanced Email](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.qs.enhancedemail&hl=en) and I love it. Its screen-real-estate-efficient UI is based on the Gingerbread client and the dev team is very responsive to user suggestions and feedback. And it doesn't kill battery life like Touchdown.